# How to get name of ODBC driver's DLL file for a given ODBC driver

Tags: odbc

How do I programatically get the name of an ODBC driver's DLL file for a given ODBC driver. For example, given "SQL Server Native Client 10.0" I want to find the name of that driver's DLL file: sqlncli10.dll. I can see this in REGEDIT in the "Driver" entry in the registry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI. If I try to read the value from the registry in my code it returns an empty string. I also tried using the ODBC API function SQLDrivers. The code below successfully returns all the values of the attributes in the Attribs variable except "Driver". Everything is there - APILevel, ConnectFunctions, CPTimeout, etc - but "Driver" is not in the list.

```
repeat
  Status := SQLDrivers (HENV, SQL_FETCH_NEXT, PAnsiChar(DriverName), 255,
            NameLen, PAnsiChar(Attribs), 1024, AttrLen);
  if Status = 0 then begin
    List.Add(DriverName);
    List.Add(Attribs);
  end;
until Status <> 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SQLGetInfo()` with  `InfoType=SQL_DRIVER_NAME`

I hope this will look like:

```
Status := SQLGetInfo(ConnEnv, SQL_DRIVER_NAME, PAnsiChar(DriverName), 255, NameLen);
```

But this function works with already connected database.

I tried `SQLDrives()` and you are right: in my environment this function also do not return DLL name. So I tried to read it from registry and it worked this way:

```
  DLLName := RegGetStringDirect(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\'  + DriverName, 'Driver');
```

For driver: `IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER` I  got: `C:\informix\bin\iclit09b.dll`

For driver: `SQL Server` I  got: `C:\WINDOWS\system32\SQLSRV32.dll`

`RegGetStringDirect()` is my function based on Windows API to read something from registry.

EDIT:

Two functions to read "SQL Server" ODBC driver dll name by Ron Schuster moved from comment:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
//using Windows API calls 
var 
  KeyName, ValueName, Value: string; 
  Key: HKEY; 
  ValueSize: Integer; 
begin
  ValueName := 'Driver';
  KeyName := 'SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\SQL Native Client';
  if RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, PChar(KeyName), 0, KEY_READ, Key) = 0 then
    if RegQueryValueEx(Key, PChar(ValueName), nil, nil, nil, @ValueSize) = 0 then begin
      SetLength(Value, ValueSize);
      RegQueryValueEx(Key, PChar(ValueName), nil, nil, PByte(Value), @ValueSize);
      ShowMessage(Value);
    end;
end; 

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
//using TRegistry class 
var
  KeyName, ValueName, Value: string;
  Reg: TRegistry;
begin
  ValueName := 'Driver';
  KeyName := 'SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\SQL Native Client';
  Reg := TRegistry.Create;
  try
    Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    if Reg.OpenKeyReadOnly(KeyName) then begin
      Value := Reg.ReadString(ValueName);
      ShowMessage(Value);
    end;
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Doesn't this function return info about an existing connection? At the point in the code where I do this I don't have a connection. I just have a driver name. If SQLGetInfo is my only option I suppose I could change the program to make the connection earlier just to get this info. This in Delphi XE and I am using a TDatabase component to connect through an ODBC DSN. I don't how I would get the value for HENV from that.

Comment: You are right, SQLGetInfo() requires connection. I tried to read DLL name from registry and it worked. Try again and try to do it using Windows API: `RegOpenKeyExA()`, `RegQueryValueExA()`

Comment: I changed my code that reads the registry and was able to successfully read the Driver value. I was able to do it two different ways. Here is the Delphi code.

Comment: procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  //using Windows API calls
  var
   KeyName, ValueName, Value: string;
   Key: HKEY;
   ValueSize: Integer;
  begin
   ValueName := 'Driver';
   KeyName := 'SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\SQL Native Client';
   if RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, PChar(KeyName), 0, KEY_READ, Key) = 0 then
    if RegQueryValueEx(Key, PChar(ValueName), nil, nil, nil, @ValueSize) = 0 then begin
     SetLength(Value, ValueSize);
     RegQueryValueEx(Key, PChar(ValueName), nil, nil, PByte(Value), @ValueSize);
     ShowMessage(Value);
    end;
  end;

Comment: procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    //using TRegistry class
  var
   KeyName, ValueName, Value: string;
   Reg: TRegistry;
  begin
   ValueName := 'Driver';
   KeyName := 'SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\SQL Native Client';
   Reg := TRegistry.Create;
   try
    Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    if Reg.OpenKeyReadOnly(KeyName) then begin
     Value := Reg.ReadString(ValueName);
     ShowMessage(Value);
    end;
   finally
    Reg.Free;
   end;
  end;

Comment: Nice that it works for you. I edited my answer adding your functions with some formatting.